# Installing hadoop 2.0.0

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop and I'm stuck with installation of hadoop-2.0.0-alpha in mac. 'conf' folder is not found in this release,but most of the installation instructions in google points to conf. Can anyone point me to the recent link?

Comment: Why 2.0.0 alpha and not 2.2.0 which is stable?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same today, but ended up getting good advice to stick with 1.0.3 right now, since 2.0.0 is in alpha. I found really good Mac OS X Lion instructions for 1.0.3, that got me up and running fairly quickly.

http://www.jdxyw.com/?p=2030

Answer (score 0):

The configurations file in hadooop 2.0.0 are in hadoop/etc/hadoop folder and the link to follow for installation is given below. Please have a look.

http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/

Answer (score 0):

You can create it yourself,just do it.